# How to Connect Compose for PostgreSQL from IBM Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ibm-cloud, compose-db, ibm-cloud-functions

I am using IBM Cloud Functions to convert the audio file into text and I am using IBM Watson speech to text service for that. Here I want to store the transcript to PostgreSQL Database. Is there any connection between IBM Cloud Functions and Compose for PostgreSQL service, So that I can store transcript to database.

I am using Node Runtime in cloud function.

Comment: have you tried using a node module like [`pg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)? not sure if you have seen this example which [shows you how to connect to an IBM Compose for PostgreSQL for Bluemix service using Node.js](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/compose-postgresql-helloworld-nodejs)

Comment: @Mdumanoj - Did the information above help you?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Node.js module **pg** that is included in the Cloud Functions runtime works well. The following is a function stub that works for me ([taken from this GitHub repo](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/slack-chatbot-database-watson/blob/master/eventFetch.pg.js)):

```
function myactualfunc(connection, some params) {
  const client=new Client({
    connectionString: connection['postgres']['composed'][0],
    ssl: true
  });

  return client.connect()
     .then(() =>
          client.query(
            "select ....",
            query-parameters))
     .then(res => perform some processing here)
     .then(() => client.end())
     .then(() => {return {"result": my-result} })
     .catch(e => {return {"error": e}})
}

function main({some params, __bx_creds: {'databases-for-postgresql': {connection}}}) {
    return myactualfunc(connection,some params);
}
```